# 2017 Accord Sport

Tags: honda, battery, accord

Having issues with battery dying all the time. Had to get a boost 5 times in last 8 days. Dealership is brushing it off and saying battery is fine. They tell me to start it before bed for a bit as it seems to die while sitting overnight. This is the most ridiculous thing I have ever heard. My car has 7000 kilometers on it!

Its currently back at dealership being looked at again. They have already called once telling me battery is fine. I don't care if battery is showing fine on your little machine, fix the fu@king problem!! Its not normal for a battery to keep dying in a new car. They seem to think its no big deal.

Anyone have any ideas or have similar issue with 2017 Accord?

Comment: Take it to another dealer - that one can't tell his a*se from his elbow.. Or they don't have anyone that understand vehicle electrics...

Comment: Talk to the Service Manager. If they are of no help, talk to the dealership General Manager. If that doesn't work, take it up to the Honda Regional Manager. They'll get some action for you. If you get to the Regional rep, believe me, the dealership will start jumping through their shorts to get stuff done for you. They do not want to mess with their franchise and the Regional rep can do that.

Comment: Do note how warranty stuff works. Honda Corporation reimburses dealerships for warranty work. You can go to ANY dealer.  Don't feel obligated to use the dealership where you purchased the vehicle.